# Why isn't my imported database showing up? install.php pops up and adds new tables to the database

Tags: migration, localhost, backup, xampp

I imported my live sites SQL backup into Xampp. I have named the new database `wordpress` and configured `wp-config.php` with the database name `wordpress`, user `root`, empty password.

Then I went to localhost/wordpress and it prompted me to `install.php` and I entered site name, user, password, e-mail etc. I then logged in and noticed my posts were not there. So I checked the database and there was a new set of tables added. So I selected all of them and dropped them hoping it would activate the backup I have in there. No luck. I went to localhost/wordpress and `install.php` prompted me for the same info and again created those tables in the database.

I also saw several posts suggesting to delete the `index.html` in Xampp so I did that and it did nothing.

How do I view the data from the backup I have in the database?

Comment: you said you see two sets of tables. what is the prefix of the tables you want to use (default is `wp_` but may be different). make sure this prefix matches what's defined in your `wp-config.php`

Comment: I changed the table prefix in wp-config.  The db prefix is wp_fgfg_ so I changed wp-config to reflect that and when I ran install.php it created new tables in the database that have the prefix wp_fgfg without the _ at the end.  

I did this all on my server and it worked fine and I am doing the same exact thing with XAMPP and it doesn't work.

Comment: I also changed the urls already in the options table.  Do I have to open the DB and do a find and replace and then import it again?  I don't assume that is the issue here tho.

Comment: There is also this in the DB and it seems suspect to me even tho I know nothing about any of this really...                            CREATE TABLE `wp_fgfg_advps_optionset` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `template` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `plist` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `query` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `slider` text NOT NULL,
  `caro_ticker` text NOT NULL,
  `container` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `navigation` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Comment: change the value in `wp-config.php` to "wp_fgfg" - no _ on the end.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

Your issue likely lies somewhere within `wp-config.php`.  You should not need to run any install if your tables already exist, the `wp-admin/install.php` is only used when no tables are detected with the settings in `wp-config.php`.

Going through parameter by parameter, I'll give you some idea of what everything is.

`DB_NAME` is the name of the database that WordPress should access.  Make sure this is set to the database that you want to use.

`DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` are the login credentials.  As you are not getting a database connection error, these are likely correct.

`DB_HOST` is how WordPress is to connect to the database.  Again, no database error likely means this is fine.

Don't worry about `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` unless you have specific reasons to change them, it's just database settings.

The last thing you need to worry about is `$table_prefix`.  Based on the comments, my best guess is that this is your issue.  If you look at the tables you imported, they should all be named something like `wp_posts`, `wp_options`, etc.  Whatever the common thread between them is is what you need to set as the prefix.  Make sure you set it EXACTLY the same, including the `_` if it's on there. WordPress doesn't add anything to this, it just concatenates the table name onto the end of it.

Comment: great point. Keep in mind, the prefix is towards the bottom of the config file! I forgot it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$table_prefix` in `wp-config.php` worked for me (default is `wp_`).